# What causes pandas pivot_table to fail?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe. When I try to create a pivot, there is no data in the pivot (i.e. only the index, but no columns) when I do it like this. The data type of amount columns is **object**, not **float**.

```
pivot = table.pivot_table(index='Date', 
                          columns='Currency', 
                          values='Amount',
                          aggfunc='sum')
```

However, when I use aggfunc count it works.

```
pivot = table.pivot_table(index='Date', 
                          columns='Currency', 
                          values='Amount',
                          aggfunc=**'count'**)
```

Also, if I create a pivot through a workaround, it works

```
pivot = table.groupby(['Date', 'Currency'])['Amount'].sum().unstack()
```

When I change the data type of **Amount** column to **float**, the normal pivot works (the one shown first).

Do you know what causes this issue when data type is **object**? Then it sometimes works, sometimes not, and I would really like to understand the logic that makes it fail.

Comment: Everything can be counted, but not all objects support addition. What is the original type?

Comment: @mozway, the original type is object, but they are numbers. As I tell above, summing works fine with groupby & unstack combination.

Comment: This is very weird, `object` usually indicates strings, but if you had string this should not raise an error, just concatenate the digits (`'1'`+`'2'` = `'12'`), please give more details on **how** it fails